# Node.js REST API versioning the right way?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, versioning

I would like to manage my REST API based on URL version specifying.

For example:

```
api.mydomain.com/v1/rides/
// will return all rides based on v1.

api.mydomain.com/v2/rides/
// will return all rides based on v2 (probably with some breaking changes).

api.mydomain.com/rides/
// will return all rides based on v2, since v2 is the newest.
```

That's awesome.

Before we get started dealing with the practical way of handling this,
We should talk about the logical "default newest versioning" - I mean, if user does not go to specify any kind of version, should I serve him with the newest version or throw a 404 not found error?

***Should I oblige the user to specify an API version? ***

***If I do, is there any standard of "parsing" the specific / newest version? ***

I tell you why I'm concern about this: Let's say that "Dan" has an app installed which relies on the newest API endpoint (V1 for example), then I release V2 which has braking changes.
Since Dans "listens" to the newest version by default, Dan's app is going to crash.

That is not a good behavior at all.
Maybe should I prevent using the "default newest versioning"?
Maybe should I use Dan's app to listen for a specific version, while remote developers accessing my API as a web service can have the privilege to choose between specific version or the newest by default?

**Is there any standard? **

**

**Now let's talk practically. ** Let's say that I have a router handling those requests, maybe something like this:

```
// app.js file

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  try {
    require('../resources/' + req.url.split('/')[1] + '/' + req.url.split('/')[1] + '-router')(app);
    next();
  } catch(err) {
    dep.cast(res, 404, new Error("Not Found"));
  }
});
```

And some handler, like this:

```
// resources/rides/rides-router.js file

module.exports = function(app) {

  // GET ride - select a ride
  app.get("/v1/rides/:id", dep.verifyToken(), require('./api/v1/get-ride'));
  app.get("/v2/rides/:id", dep.verifyToken(), require('./api/v2/get-ride'));

  // POST ride - insert a new ride
  app.post("/v1/rides", dep.verifyToken(), require('./api/v1/set-ride'));

}
```

As you can see, I have a handler which sends the requests to the specific divisions in the API, split by V1, V2, etc...

It makes me wonder if it's right to have the same page containing the same function over and over in different folders, one for V1 and one for V2.
Of course, with some braking changes, but they are probably going to be similar. Is it not bordering with repetitive code?

Look at the project structure:

[image]

What do you think about this?

Comment: REST is just a generalization of the Web we use everyday. Therefore looking at how stuff is versioned on the Web does make sense. I.e. [HTML is versioned by its media-type](https://www.w3.org/blog/2007/05/html-and-version-mechanisms/) and kept backwards compatible. The media type is actually the coupling part between clients and servers and the representation formats exchanged between both should be described and specified. Versioning the endpoint seems to be an RPC like thing IMO as a change here might easily break clients that have no knowlege on how to handle such messages exchanged.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Instead of adding version in every route you can add it in app level. So It won't be tightly coupled with API route.

```
import * as express from 'express';

// v1/get-ride.js
const router = express.Router();
router.post('/rides/:id', dep.verifyToken(), (req, res) => {
    // Your code
});
app.use('/v1', router);


// v2/get-ride.js
const router = express.Router();
router.post('/rides/:id', dep.verifyToken(), (req, res) => {
    // Your code
});
app.use('/v2', router);
```

Comment: So you say that I dont need the rides-router.js which is in the "rides" directory at all? In which way to load the v1/get-ride.js and v2/get-ride.js so they will be performed?

Comment: you can avoid hard coding versions in every route, using app.use.

Comment: May I send you github and you create a pull request modifying your agendas? Whats your Github user if then.

Comment: where to put the controllers and routes folder, does it go api => v1 => controllers or api => controllers => v1

Answer (score 8):

I would recommend using [node-express-versioning](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-routes-versioning) module instead.

It would help you to support multiple versions without changing the url of API, just send the version of API and  direct the call to that version route-controller.

```
*

*//version taken out from header

    app.use(function(req, res, next)
    {
       req.version = req.headers['accept-version'];
       console.log(req.version);
       next();
    });

    //version path defined

    app.use('/api', versionRoutes({  
       "1.0.0": respondV1,
       "2.0.0": respondV2
    }));

    function respondV1(req, res, next)
     {   
        app.use('/api',routeV1);
        next();
     }
    function respondV2(req, res, next)
    {
       app.use('/api',routeV2);
       next();
    }*
```

*

Comment: Hi, just checked the library it just has 58 stars. Is there any other library as well which has more wider support and community base?

Answer (score 4):

There's no "right way" to do API versioning.

However, URI based global versioning is not at all RESTful.

Phil Sturgeon of "APIs you won't hate" recommends an API Evolution approach instead.

See: https://apisyouwonthate.com/blog/api-evolution-for-rest-http-apis

Have you considered this as an option?